# Add column from one dataframe to another, for values present in overlapping column

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
In [46]: import pandas as pd

In [47]: df_3 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(6,2), columns=["a", "z"])


In [48]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(4,3), columns=["a", "b", "c"])

In [49]: df
Out[49]: 
   a   b   c
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11

[4 rows x 3 columns]

In [50]: df_3
Out[50]: 
    a   z
0   0   1  # present in df 
1   2   3
2   4   5
3   6   7  # present in df
4   8   9
5  10  11

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to add column z to `df`, but I want the values be added only for rows that match on column `a`. If not I want a null value in place.

My desired output would look like this:

```
In [52]: df["z"] = [1, np.nan, 7, np.nan]

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
   a   b   c   z
0  0   1   2   1
1  3   4   5 NaN
2  6   7   8   7
3  9  10  11 NaN

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

I tried naive attempts, like

```
In [57]: df.merge(df_3, on=["a"])
Out[57]: 
   a  b  c  z
0  0  1  2  1
1  6  7  8  7

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

Which does not give me the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just perform a [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) on 'a' column and perform a left type merge:

```
In [72]:

df.merge(df_3, on='a', how='left')
Out[72]:
   a   b   c   z
0  0   1   2   1
1  3   4   5 NaN
2  6   7   8   7
3  9  10  11 NaN
```

The reason you got this result:

```
In [57]: df.merge(df_3, on=["a"])
Out[57]: 
   a  b  c  z
0  0  1  2  1
1  6  7  8  7

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

is because the default type of merge is 'inner' so values have to exist in both lhs and rhs, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging